# How can I get iCloud Photo Library to use less storage space on my iPad?

Tags: ipad, icloud, photos, storage

My iPad only has 16 GB of space, and I have iCloud Photo Library switch on but set to "Optimise iPad Storage". However, my iPad is now showing "0 bytes" available, and my Photo Library is taking up 2.1 GB.

Shouldn't Photos & Camera automatically optimise based upon how much storage I have left? I can't imagine the 2.1 GB is just thumbnails? How can I flush my photos so none of them are stored on the device?